# How to append a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested

How can I divide all of the data in the second row by two?

```
recipe  = [
    ['eggs', 'flour', 'meat'],
    [4, 250, 5],
    ['large','grams', 'kg'],
]
```

I've tried starting with

```
for row[2] in recipe:
```

But I get an error saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/g/Documents/reicpe.py", line 7, in 
>       for row[2] in meat_pie:
>
> NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recipe  = [
    ['eggs', 'flour', 'meat'],
    [4, 250, 5],
    ['large','grams', 'kg'],
]
```

Leaving aside this would be far better as a dictionary, if you want to divide the quantities by two, and change what you have stored :

```
for quantity, index in enumerate(recipe[1])
    recipe[1][index] = quantity/2
```

A better way would be to use a dictionary, which allows you to give names to data items :

```
recipe = {"eggs":{"quantity":4, "measurement":"large"},
         "flour":{"quantity":250,"measurement":"grams"}, 
         "meat":{"quantity":5,"measurement":"kg"}}
```

and now division by two becomes :

```
for ingredient in recipe:
    recipe[ingredient]["quantity"] = recipe[ingredient]["quantity"]/2
```

and print the recipe becomes :

```
for ingredient in recipe:
    print "{} {} {}".format(recipe[ingredient]["quantity"], recipe[ingredient]["measurement"], ingredient)
```

this generates :

```
4 large eggs
250 grams flour
5 kg meat
```

and no faffing about with index numbers etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use *list comprehension* and do it in one single line without the *for-loop*:

```
recipe[1] = [num / 2 for num in recipe[1]]
```

Code Explanation `[num / 2 for num in recipe[1]]`:

- `recipe[1]`:  This is a list, it's the second element of `recipe` list

  *The second element of* `recipe` *is:* `[4, 250, 5]`
- `for num in recipe[1]`: This mean that we're going to loop over the elements of `recipe[1]`, so `num` it's a variable, and it's value changes over the list elements in each iteration.
- `num / 2`: It's obvious that we get num and divide by 2

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate on the wrong portion.  When you use the statement: `for i in list`, `i` is created as a new variable (as if you had just stated `i = 5`).  So at that point, it does not have a getter (index or otherwise) for element 5 (and it is not a valid variable name).

To fix your iteration issue try:

`for row in mylist[index]:`

That will iterate over the list at index in mylist, of course remember that lists are 0 indexed (your numbers are at index 1).

You're going to have another issue shortly with updating the values in your array, however, since the process will create a copy the way you're doing it.  A simple fix is to use `enumerate` (but I will leave that up to you to try out before giving it to you!)

Answer (score 0):

`recipe[1]` gives you the **second** list inside the recipe list. Remember, list index always start with 0.

Then:

```
for row in recipe[1]:
```

Will iterate with `row` taking the value of each of the values inside `recipe[1]`.